# Scrapy File Downloads with Custom Names - Subclass Inheritance Issue

Tags: python, inheritance, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm building a simple spider to crawl a structured site and download *.txt files. I've managed to get everything working except for a custom FilesPipeline class.

My goal is to download *.txt files into directories according to their url location. I can achieve my goal if I edit the Scrapy class directly (shown below)

*files.py -> FilesPipeline::file_path()*

```
...
# return 'full/%s%s' % (media_guid, media_ext)
return url.split('example.com/')[1]
```

I want to overload the class properly but haven't been successful. I'm not sure what I should be doing differently. The spider will run with no warnings or errors but wont download files.

*settings.py*

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'myspider.pipelines.MySpiderFilesPipeline': 1,
'myspider.pipelines.MySpiderPipeline': 300,
}
```

*spider.py*

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import re
from myspider.items import MySpiderItem

class SpideySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'spidey'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/']

    rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='', restrict_xpaths='//tr/td/a', deny_extensions='html'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

def parse_item(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//tr/td/a')
    for link in links:
        i = MySpiderItem()
        i['title'] = response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        i['href'] = link.xpath('@href').extract()
        i['text'] = link.xpath('text()').extract()
        i["current_url"] = response.url
        referring_url = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
        i['referring_url'] = referring_url
        i['depth'] = response.meta['depth']

        if i['text'][0]:
            if re.match('^#.*\.txt$', i['text'][0]) is not None:
                i['file_urls'] = [ response.urljoin(i['href'][0]) ]

        yield i
```

*pipelines.py*

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.files import FilesPipeline, FSFilesStore
import json
import re

class MySpiderPipeline(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.file = open('items.json', 'wb')

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    valid = True
    for data in item:
        if not data:
            valid = False
            raise DropItem("Missing {0}!".format(data))
    if re.match('^#.*\.html$', item['text'][0]) is not None:
        valid = False
        raise DropItem("HTML File")
    if re.match('^#.*\.txt$', item['text'][0]) is not None:
        pass

    line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
    self.file.write(line)
    return item

class MySpiderFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):

_url_breakstring = "example.com/"

def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.files_urls_field, [])]

def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):

    return url.split(_url_breakstring)[1]
    # media_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()  # change to request.url after deprecation
    # media_ext = os.path.splitext(url)[1]  # change to request.url after deprecation
    # return 'full/%s%s' % (media_guid, media_ext)
```

Answer (score 0):

For pipeline class add `__init__` method for example:

```
class GCSFilePipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def __init__(self, store_uri, download_func=None, settings=None):
        super().__init__(store_uri, settings=settings, download_func=download_func)
```